# <figure> & <figcapture> tags in CKeditor

Tags: ckeditor

Going a little insane trying to tell the CKeditor v4.4.2 instance embedded in my Kentico CMS to stop filtering & allow whatever I want.

Case in point, it keeps messing up my figure & figcapture tags, sometimes closing incorrectly, sometimes removing them, sometimes replacing the tag with paragraph tags.

I've spent several days trying to track this down, and have tried plenty:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
config.extraAllowedContent = 'figure figcapture';
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.figure = 1;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$editable.figcaption = 1;
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['figure'] = false;'
CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['figcapture'] = false;
config.protectedSource.push( /<figure[\s\S]*?>/gi ) ;
config.protectedSource.push( /<\/figure[\s\S]*?>/gi ) ; 
config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
```

None of this works. None of it even seems to change the behavior. 
What could I possibly be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<figcapture>`? There's no such element in HTML. What you meant is `<figcaption>` and this would be enough:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'figure figcaption';
```

Comment: You are right, I totally fumbled the typing & cascaded it thru cut & paste. Sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes...thanks.